# Managing views with complex states

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js app, whose views have multiple states, which differ substantially from each other ("View","Edit", etc). There are at least 2 different templates for every view. This is OK. My problem is with the JS view managing code.

I rely on an initalize-thin-render-thick approach (which, I think is pretty bad), where the render method is where 80%-90% of the logic occurs. When I want to change the state, I simply call the render method with a specific parameter ("view","edit"). On the basis of that, the view decides what to show and what not, to which events to bind, etc.

I think this is bad, because, on one side it puts bottlenecks on the rendering process, on another, it is not proper state machine, which means that I am not carrying about possible callbacks that might have been bound previously. When I receive the view, I simply clean the view and that's it.

I also observed, that I am not using the delegated event system, provided by backbone, which I think is another minus, because I think, it is very well implemented (BTW, does it make sure to unbind callbacks, when a certain DOM element is removed?)

I think I need some serious refactoring. Please, help with some advice, as to what the best approach for a multi-state Backone view would be.

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do for these cases is to make a toplevel view that manages a subview for each individual state (index, show, edit, etc.).  When a user action is invoked, e.g. "edit this user", "delete this user", "save my changes", the active state view signals the router (directly, or through a hyperlink), and the router will tell the toplevel view to update its state.

Continuing the user editor example, let's say that I have a top level view called UserEditorView.  It renders a basic container for the user editor (title bars, etc.) and then, by default, instantiates and renders Users.IndexView inside that container.

Users.IndexView renders the list of users.  Next to each user is an edit icon, which is a link to "#users/555/edit".  So, when the user clicks it, that event goes to the router, which tells UserEditorView, "hey, I want to edit user #555".  And then UserEditorView will remove the IndexView (by calling its .remove() method), instantiate Users.EditView for the appropriate user model, and put the EditView into the container.

When the user is done editing the user, she clicks on "Save", and then EditView saves the model.  Now we need to get back to the IndexView.  EditView calls window.router.navigate('users', { trigger: true }), so the URL gets updated and the router gets invoked.  The router then calls .showIndex() on the UserEditorView, and the UserEditorView does the swap back to IndexView from EditView.

Answer (score 0):

On a simple way to manage unloading of events, I've found [this article on zombie views quite useful](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/).

Basically, I don't have a toplevel view, but I render all the views using a view handler that takes care of the views for a given container.

To make your renderer thinner, I would recommend using routes. They are easy to setup, and you can have different views for each route. Or, what I'm used to do is just to have different templates. Using a general Backbone.View overwrite:

```
Backbone.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(attrs) {
      attrs = attrs || {}
      if(!_.isUndefined(attrs.template)) {
        this.template = attrs.template;
      }
    }
});
```

I've noticed that I reuse views in two ways:
1. edit views differ only in the underlying model and template, but not the associated logic (clicking the submit validates and saves the model)
2. the same view can be reused in several places with different templates (like a list of users as a ranking or you accounts)

With the above extension, I can pass {template: '/my/current/template/} to the view, and it will be rendered as I want. Together with routes, I finally got a flexible, easy to understand and thin setup.